# Glitch with swiper coverflow effect

Tags: html, css, sass, swiper.js

So I am currently trying to add a swiper from swiperJS in my website using the coverflow effect but came to a problem,in the same page I have a header that is in position : sticky and when the header is just over the swiper the slides seems to glitch and flicker. The problem seems to come from the 3d used for the effect everytime I deactivate either transform : translate3d or transform-style :preserve-3d the problem go away since there is no more coverflow effect. I was wondering if there was a way to by-pass this problem. I also realized that this problem only happens using chrome in desktop. On every mobile that I tested(safari and chrome) it worked and even on firefox desktop. The problem is really only on chrome desktop.

I saw on other forums that some people had problems with transform-style: preserve-3d and transform: translate3d and people said to had transform translate3d(0) on the element but nothing that I saw worked.